# How to make all column headers sticky(fixed) in ag-grid in angular while page scrolling?

Tags: css, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-validation

I have tried this for two days but still I couldn't find the solution can any one please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your header HTML be like:

the CSS for it to stick on top must be:

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: i tried this already but when we give position as fixed it is at the top of the page, but i need like after scrolling down to the header position it should be fixed at the top.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sticky

```
    .header {position: sticky;}
```